# If the A* algorithm explores more than one path, how do you choose the best one?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, path-finding

I have been working on a C# implementation of the A* pathfinding algorithm, and now that I have managed to get it to find a path from the starting point to the destination, I was wondering how I could choose the best path.

To clarify, if I make the program find a route from the square with a yellow border to the square with a green border (where dark grey squares cannot be crossed), the program will add all of the red squares to its 'closed' array.

[image]

As you can see, this isn't a direct route. How would I get the actual path from the closed array? By the way, I have disabled diagonal movement.

Comment: The A* algorithm already chooses the best (cheapest) path. Your implementation might be incorrect.

Comment: @itsme86 Incomplete, rather

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Incomplete.I found this page (http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm) very helpful when implementing my own A* algorithm some time ago.

Comment: @itsme86 The paragraph starting "So how do we determine the path?" seems to answer my question. Thanks! Btw: you may want to post the gist as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: What "isn't a direct route"? In A* (as in most pathfinding algorithms) you know where you come from in each visited node... You seem to imply that path would include all visited node - why?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't exactly manage to derive a route from the nodes that had been explored at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've done A*, but if I recall correctly, you can trace backwards, starting from the end and following the path of least distance.

[image]

So if the numbers on this grid represent the distance to the yellow square, the shortest path could be found by starting at the green square (distance 12), and continually moving onto neighbors with the least distance until reaching the yellow square.

So you'd go 12 -> 11 -> 10 -> 9 ... -> 0